Angular Reload: Dynamic TenantID Identification & Universal Data Update Implementation
In my Angular application, I encounter the need to check the tenantId and load relevant information when the page is reloaded. Currently, I’ve implemented this logic directly in multiple places throughout my code (in every component). However, I’d like to centralize this implementation to avoid redundancy. How can I create a common solution that can be easily called from any component?
below is my implementation
//checking the route when reloading the page
this.route.paramMap
.pipe(
  takeUntil(this._unsubscribeAll),
  switchMap((params: Params) => {
    const tenantId = params.get('tenantId');
    if (tenantId) {
      return this._apiService.getTenants();
    } else {
      return of(null); // No tenantId, return an observable to avoid unnecessary subscriptions
    }
  }),
  filter(tenants => tenants !== null),
  take(1) // only need 1 take tenant
).subscribe(
  (tenants: Tenant[]) => {
    const tenantId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('tenantId'); 
    const activeRouteTenant = tenants.find(
      tenant => tenant.name === tenantId
    );
    if (activeRouteTenant) {
      this._tenantService.updateTenant(activeRouteTenant);
    }
       // Ensure components are checked for changes
       this._changeDetectorRef.markForCheck();
       this.initialDashboardInformation()
  }
)

Could you please assist me on this Thank you so much :D

You could try using route guards. First argument of canActivate is a snapshot of the route.
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
   console.log(route.paramMap.get('tenantId'));
}

The route guard can be used with multiple components.
